# Question regarding basic counting principles

Tags: combinatorics

I was going over some questions in basic counting and I got stuck on this question :

> What is the probability that if I draw $65$ cards uniformly at random, with replacement, from the deck, every card is drawn at least once?

I know the answer has something to do with Stirling's number but the formula my lecturer gave me doesn't make sense to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the deck has 52 cards?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/516340/28555

Comment: yes 52 cars in a deck

Comment: I modified and reposted my answer below to Fred Kline's link. I also added an example.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is $$\frac{{65\brace52}52!}{52^{65}}.$$

**Explanation**: Suppose we have a deck of $k$ cards, say $C=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots, c_k\}$, and we draw, with replacement, $n\geq k$ of them. Let $(d_1,\ldots, d_n)$ be the sequence of draws (so each $d_j\in C$). I'll call this a *drawing*.

Obviously there are $k^n$ possible drawings.

In how many drawings is each card chosen at least once? I'll call these *good* drawings. Well, let $(d_1,\ldots, d_n)$ be a drawing and suppose we have $k$ buckets labelled $\{c_1,c_2,\ldots, c_k\}$. Place $d_j$ into bucket $c_i$ when $d_j=c_i$. Then we know that the drawing is good if and only if each bucket is non-empty.

Now, suppose we have $k$ buckets, and we label them with labels $c_1,\ldots, c_k$, each bucket getting a different label. There are $k!$ ways of doing this.

Now place the symbols $\{D_1,\ldots, D_n\}$ into the buckets, each bucket getting at least one symbol. There are ${n\brace k}$ ways of doing this, where ${n\brace k}$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Then we can define a good drawing $(d_1,\ldots, d_n)$ by setting $d_j=c_i$ if and only if $D_j$ was placed in bucket labelled $c_i$.

Thus there are exactly ${n\brace k}k!$ good drawings and so the probability that a drawing is good is $$\frac{{n\brace k} k!}{k^{n}}.$$

Comment: Is the numbers inside the curly bracket combinations or permuatations?

Comment: Well, ${n\brace k}$ is *defined* to be the number of ways of splitting up a set with $n$ elements into $k$ non-empty parts. You can follow the link to get more info about how this number is actually calculated.