# Coupon Collector Problem with a constant probability of getting a coupon

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

My question includes a simple modification to well-known Coupon Collector Problem.

In this version there is a constant probability of getting a coupon at each trial. How this changes the original problem?

Denote by $T_m$ the number of trial required to collect all m coupons. Denote by $p$ the probability of getting a coupon at a trial.

I think the expectation of $T_m$ is simply $$\rm E[T_m] = \frac{m}{p} \sum_{I=1}^m \frac{1}{i}.$$

However, I am not sure about the distribution of $T_m$. I think it may include a Binomial distribution. Can you help about that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Look at the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693222/combinatorics-of-the-coupon-collectors-problem) to see how to compute the distribution in the standard problem.  For the modified problem it should be straightforward to generalize this.

We can imagine that we have $m$ ordinary coupons, each of which occurs with probability $\frac pn$, and one blank coupon, which occurs with probability $1-p$.  For $M>=m$ we want the probability $\pi_M$ that in $M$ trials we collect all $m$ non-blank coupons.  (If we want the probability that it takes exactly $M$ trials to get all the non-blank-coupons, this is simply $\pi_M-\pi_{M-1}$.)

This is the sum from $k=0$ to $k=M-m$ that we collect exactly $k$ blank coupons, and in the other $M-k$ trails, we collect only non-blank coupons, and get at least one of each.  The second part of this is just an ordinary coupon collector's problem.

This will be a messy expression.  I don't know if it simplifies at all.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the part that we have $k= M- m$ blank coupon. We still might have more than $m$ non-blank coupons, so the repetitions are still allowed. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user_1 I said we can have anywhere from $k=0$ to $k=M-m$ blank coupons.  It's a sum