# Find the probability that each event occurs at least once

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Question**: Let $\omega_1,\omega_2,\cdots,\omega_k$ be $k$ distinct events. When we perform a random test, the outcome $\omega_1,\omega_2,\cdots,\omega_k$ occurs with equal possibility $\frac{1}{k}$. Now we perform the random test independently for $m$ times, then what is the possibility that each event occurs at least once?

**Example**: For $k=6$, the question is, after we throw a dice for $m$ times, what is the possibility that each of the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ occurs at least once?

**My Solution**: Consider the inclusion-exclusion principle. The possibility is $1$ minus the possibility that one event doesn't occur, plus the possibility that two events don't occur, minus the possibility that three events don't occur, ... Then the result is
$$
P=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}{(-1)}^i\binom{k}{i}{\left(\frac{k-i}{k}\right)}^m
$$
**My Question**: Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem (which yields a simpler expression rather than a summation)?

Comment: This is related to Coupon collector's problem ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)). I'm not familiar with this topic, but answers in Math.SE (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1454749/702715) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/693254/702715)) seem to indicate that there are no simpler way to compute the value.

Comment: @VTand thans for your comment. I found that my formula is like the Stirling number of the second kind, except that the latter is divided my $k!$ while mine is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many problems can be fitted into a balls-in-bins type.
Look at it as the probability of putting distinct balls into distincr bins with no bin empty.
Firstly counting the # of ways *m* balls can be put in *k* *identical* bins, the answer (by the very *definition* of Stirling numbers of the second kind, is $\large{m\brace k}$

But since our bins are distinct, they can be permuted in $k!$ ways, so the favourable count is $k!\large{m\brace k}$ against a total of $k^m$ ways

thus $Pr = \huge\frac{k!\Large{m\brace k}}{k^m}$