# Finding the probability of an event with the inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: probability

We are given a stack of presents received in a bit hday. Each of them contains one of $5$ different figures $F_1,...,F_5.$ We assume that the probability of finding any of those figures is the same, $\mathbb{P} = \frac{1}{5}.$ I want to use the inclusion-exclusion principle in calculating the probability of finding only the figures $F_1,F_2,F_3$ in 6 sequential presents. In case one would write down the inclusion-exclusion principle given 6 events, it becomes too complex. I do not understand how to define appropriately the events we need in finding the required probability. I will appreciate your support in providing some hints or a solution proposal. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify... do you want only those outcomes where all three of these occurred?  Or at most these three having occurred?  If the latter, then this is just a binomial distribution.  If it is the former... then I recommend using Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind if you wish to avoid a (*more obviously*) inclusion-exclusion style argument.

Comment: Thanks. I want only the outcomes such that out of the 6 presents one gets the outcomes containing $F_1, F_2$ and $F_3.$ That means that each of these had occurred at least once. But I want to use the inclusion-exclusion principle. I do not see if I have to express the union as the union of $3$ or 6 events. In the latter case the expansion of that formula gets quite complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less elegant Inclusion-Exclusion approach:

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

The desired probability may be expressed as

$$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = 5^6.$$

That is, the denominator above represents that you have $~5~$ choices for each of the $~6~$ gifts.

So, the problem reduces to computing $~N.$

Following the model in the second link:

- Let $~S~$ denote the set of all the ways that the $~6~$ sequential presents contain no gifts other than $~F_1, ~F_2, ~$ or $~F_3.$ 
  Then
  $|S| = 3^6.~$
- For $~k \in ~\{1,2,3\}~$ let $~S_k~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ such that the constraint that the $~6~$ sequential gifts include at least one gift $~F_k~$ is **violated**.

Then,

$$N = |S| - |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3|.$$

Let :

- $T_0~$ denote $~|S|.$
- $T_1~$ denote $~|S_1| + |S_2| + |S_3|.~$
- $T_2~$ denote $~|S_1 \cap S_2| + |S_1 \cap S_3| + |S_2 \cap S_3|.$
- $T_3~$ denote $~|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3|.$

Then, per Inclusion-Exclusion theory,

$$N = T_0 - T_1 + T_2 - T_3.$$

By symmetrical considerations:

- $T_1 = 3 \times (2)^6.$ 
  That is, to compute $~|S_1|~$ note that you have exactly $~2~$ choices for each of the $~6~$ gifts. 
  Further, by symmetrical considerations, $~|S_1| = |S_2| = |S_3|.$
- By similar considerations of symmetry, 
  $T_2 = 3 \times (1^6).$
- $T_3 = (0)^6 = 0.$ 
  That is, since the set $~S~$ represents all of the ways that there can be $~6~$ sequential gifts, each of which is an element in $~\{F_1, F_2, F_3\}~$ it is not possible to have any such group of $~6~$ sequential gifts, taken from the set $~S,~$ where each of the elements in the set $~\{F_1, F_2, F_3\},~$ is excluded.

Therefore,

$$N = 3^6 - [~3 \times 2^6~] + [~3 \times 1^6].$$

Therefore, the probability is

$$\frac{3^6 - [~3 \times 2^6~] + [~3 \times 1^6]}{5^6}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your post. What is the meaning of the sets $S_k, k\in \{ =1,2,3\}? $ If the constraint is violated, the sets $S_k$ can not be subsets of S, right?

Comment: @user996159 $S_1~$ is the subset of $~S~$ where none of the $~6~$ sequential gifts were the gift $~F_1,~$ so $~S_1~$ represents that all of the $~6~$ sequential gifts were either $~F_2~$ or $~F_3.~$  $~S_2~$ and $~S_3~$ are similarly defined.

Comment: Why is $N$ not simply equal to $|S|$?

Comment: @user996159 Because of one of your comments, following the posting, where you specified that the $~6~$ gifts must include at least one occurrence of each of $~F_1, F_2, F_3.~$  The set $~S,~$ which represents all distributions of the $~6~$ gifts that do not include any occurrence of either $~F_4~$ or $~F_5,~$ includes distributions where (for example) $~F_1~$ is also excluded.  Hence the application of Inclusion-Exclusion against the subsets $~S_1, S_2, S_3.$

Comment: Thanks. I do not get the correct result, though. Should one also subtract from $|S|$ the elements of subsets of $S$ which are missing two and not only one of $F_1, F_2, F3$ ?

Comment: @user996159 : I advise against trying to take shortcuts, as you study the material.  First, review the two Inclusion-Exclusion links fairly carefully.  Then review my answer fairly carefully.  The question that you just asked seems to indicate that you didn't focus on the fact that $~N = T_0 - T_1 + T_2 - T_3.$

Comment: Thanks. Anyway the answer is deviating by almost a factor of $10.$ Subtracting didn't help much. And maybe the answer that I have is wrong and your result is true.

Comment: @user996159 What is the official answer to the problem?  Alternatively, what do you think that the answer should be?

Comment: $0.34947$ vs $0.03436.$

Comment: @user996159 Please click on the following link, so that we can discuss the problem in a chat room: [Chat Room Link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145488/problem-discussion).

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [this CV answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/588069/214015) (which builds off [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/693254/697491) that uses inclusion-exclusion):

The probability of observing $k$ unique letters in $m$ random uniform samples from an alphabet of size $n$ is:

$$\bigg\{\!{m\!\atop{k}}\bigg\}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k!}{n^m}$$

Where $\big\{\!{m\!\atop{k}}\big\}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

But you don't want just *any* set of $k$ letters, you want one specific set, so divide by the number of ways to get $k$ out of $n$ letters:

$$\bigg\{\!{m\!\atop{k}}\bigg\}\frac{k!}{n^m}$$