# Probability of choosing all distict values in a set after n tries with m selections per round

Tags: probability

I have a set of 60 unique numbers and every round I draw m unique numbers from the set.  After every round the m numbers are replaced.  I'm looking to find the probability that all 60 numbers have been selected at least once after n rounds.

I have looked at this question: [Probability of choosing 54 unique values with replacements after n tries.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189158/probability-of-choosing-54-unique-values-with-replacements-after-n-tries) and the answer there seems to be for a specific variant of my question where m=1.

Is there a more generic solution for any m?

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $S$ of $k$ numbers, the probability that none of these are chosen in any given round is ${60-k \choose m}/{60 \choose m}$ and the probability none are chosen in $n$ rounds is $\left( {60-k \choose m}/{60 \choose m}\right)^n$.  By the inclusion-exclusion principle, the probability that every number is chosen at least once in $n$ rounds is
$$ 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{60-m} {60 \choose k} (-1)^{k-1} \left(\left. {60-k \choose m}\right/{60 \choose m}\right)^n$$