# What is the probability distribution for this question?

Tags: probability, statistics, coupon-collector

I tried to find the probability distribution for this problem and then calculate the expectation of $n$. I suppose the total states of our problem would be $52^n$ and our desired states would be $52$ combination of n with permutation $52!$ for distinct cards and our probability function will be $p(n)=\frac{n!}{(n-52)!(52^n)}$ with $n = 52,53, ....$ But the summation over $p(n)$ is not $1$. I don't know what is wrong with this solution. Can anybody help? Thank you so much[image]

Comment: "I suppose the total states of our problem would be 52^n" ?? The probability space cannot depend on n the value of the random variable defined on it.

Comment: If you are only asked to calculate this expectation then I advice you *not* to use the distribution.

Comment: Why does the space not depend on n? @ Did

Comment: How can we calculate expectation without distribution? @ drhab

Comment: As @drhab wrote, it's almost never a good idea to go for the distribution if you're only interested in the expectation; the expectation is usually far easier to determine than the distribution. I marked this as a duplicate of a question asking for the expectation; if you're still interest in the distribution, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379525) as well as the links in the comments there.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at $p(53)$: $$p\left(53\right)=\frac{52}{52}\frac{\color{red}1}{\color{red}{52}}\frac{51}{52}\frac{50}{52}\cdots\frac{1}{52}+\frac{52}{52}\frac{51}{52}\frac{\color{red}2}{\color{red}{52}}\frac{50}{52}\cdots\frac{1}{52}+\cdots+\frac{52}{52}\frac{51}{52}\frac{50}{52}\cdots\frac{2}{52}\frac{\color{red}{51}}{\color{red}{52}}\frac{1}{52}$$

The colored factors correspond with the unique non-hit.

This is not the expression for $p(53)$ that you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Coupon Collector's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: Thank you very much. That is correct.