# Probability of collecting all prizes from cereal boxes

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Each cereal box contains 1 of 5 uniformly distributed prizes.  If you open 10 randomly selected boxes, what is the probability that you will get all 5 prizes?

More generally, is there a formula you can use to solve this when the number of prizes is *x* and the number of boxes is *y*?

Comment: Hint: In five arbitrary boxes there must be different prices. At the other 5 boxes the kind of prices doesn't matter.

Comment: Inclusion-Exclusion is a good approach.  More broadly, this class of problems is referred to as [Coupon Collector Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: @JeanMarie I dont think this is negative binomial.  Negative binomial applies when there are only two outcomes for each trial and the probability of successful trial is fixed.  Here there are 5 outcomes.  Or, if you  "success" is defined as getting a prize you haven't gotten yet, then the probability of a "success" changes.

Comment: @lulu Thank you.  The link does help but it provides a solution for expected value.  I don't t see there how you calculate the probability for the question I posed.  It looks like you could use the Markov inequality the article mentions to put bounds on the probability but I cant easily follow that part of the article.

Comment: Aha, I think I found it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1454749/523382

Comment: @Bart Wisialowski, My bad, you are completely right : the random variable "number of bought boxes" it is the sum of geometric laws but with **changing parameters** (there is a longer mean time to obtain the second prize, then a still longer mean time to get the third, etc.