# Find the probability distribution of minimum number of draws to get balls of each color in an urn

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, coupon-collector

An urn contains 10 black 10 white and 10 blue balls . Balls are drawn randomly with replacement Let T be the minimum number of draws required to get balls of all different colors .Find distribution of T

P(T=n)=P(T>=n)-P(T>n)

now P(T>n)=Number of ways we get only 2 balls of different colour -Number of ways we get 1 ball of different colour in n draws

only balls of two different colors are obtained with probability
$$\sum_{x=0}^n{n\choose x}(\frac {1}{3})^x(\frac {1}{3})^{n-x} + \sum_{x=0}^n {n\choose x}(\frac {1}{3})^x(\frac {1}{3})^{n-x} + \sum_{x=0}^n{n\choose x}(\frac {1}{3})^x(\frac {1}{3})^{n-x}$$

-only black or blue or white  balls are obtained with probability $(\frac {1}{3})^n +(\frac {1}{3})^n +(\frac {1}{3})^n$

how to calculate the other part  i.e. P(T>=n) please help!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: Given there are only $10$ balls of each color the chances change as the balls are drawn. You can't use $\frac 13$ without considering that.

Comment: So it is not coupon collector problem?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for formatting math on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to calculate the other part

You do not need to.

The event $\{T\,{=}\,n\}$ is the event of drawing one from three colours in the last draw, and only the remaining two colors among the preceding $n\,{-}\,1$ draws *but* those must not be all of the same colour.  (Clearly, $n$ should be at least $3$).

You evaluate the probability for this using the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

(There is no need to involve series in this.)

Answer (score 0):

See [Probability distribution in the coupon collector's problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379525). This is the special case $m=3$. Substituting that into the general solution yields

$$
\def\stir#1#2{\left\{#1\atop#2\right\}}
P(T=n)=\frac{3!}{3^n}\stir{n-1}{3-1}\;.
$$

With $\stir n2=2^{n-1}-1$, this is

$$
P(T=n)=\frac{2^{n-1}-2}{3^{n-1}}\;.
$$

This applies for $n\ge2$; clearly $P(T=1)=0$.